# Testing django pages with middleware for multihost

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-middleware

Background: I'm using the middleware `django-multihost` (http://effbot.org/zone/django-multihost.htm) to allow my single django app to respond to different hostnames from the same project.  The middleware changes the `ROOT_URLCONF` (i.e. which `urls.py` file) based on the `Host:` HTTP request header.

This works great, but I want to write some simple integration tests that check that the pages are loading properly.  Here's an example of a basic test that checks if the `/trends` page loads and that it has the text "Trends for Today" on it:

```
def test_homepage_loads(self):
    client = Client()
    client.login(username = 'testing', password = 'testing')
    page = client.get("/trends", follow = follow_redirects)
    self.assertEquals(page.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue( page.content.find('Trends for Today') > 0 )
```

Problem is, this always loads using the default ROOT_URLCONF rather than the one the Middleware would invoke.  Doesn't matter if I explicitly put the hostname into the url as in `client.get("http://secondarysite/trends")`.

How can I test on the other virtual sites with the django test client?  I'd like to invoke the middleware in the test so I can test that logic.  But if I need to I'd do something hacky like set ROOT_URLCONF for the duration of the tests, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the Django Client you can set HTTP headers like this:

```
client.get(url, HTTP_HOST = 'my.host.com')
```

Basically the `get` functions take a dict of arguments, which it will use as HTTP headers. To adhere to DRY, you could do something like this in `setup()` of the unittest class:

```
self.request_headers = { 'HTTP_HOST': 'foo' }
```

And in your test method:

```
client.get(url, **self.request_headers)
```

Note: I'm not sure if this will work for your problem. This is however the only way I can think of to set the headers.

Another solution I can think of is to set the URLConf on your test class, like this:

```
class Mytest(TestCase):
    urls = 'my.urlconf'
```

This would however not test the middleware.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.get:

```
The extra keyword arguments parameter can be used to specify headers to be sent in the request
```

So, you might try to override HTTP_HOST header.